# Concat values in associative array given same key/value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Let's say I have the following from pushing to an object which I then perform `JSON.stringify` against

```
"support_advice": [{
        "text": "",
        "group": "check_lifestyle_26",
        "value": "Physical activity & Exercise"
    }]
```

I now want to push a new item

```
"support_advice": [{
        "text": "",
        "group": "check_lifestyle_26",
        "value": "Overall General Health & Wellbeing"
    }]
```

So normally, I'd get the following

```
"support_advice": [{
        "text": "",
        "group": "check_lifestyle_26",
        "value": "Physical activity & Exercise"
    }, {
        "text": "",
        "group": "check_lifestyle_26",
        "value": "Overall General Health & Wellbeing"
    }]
```

However, would it be possible to concatenate the values based on the group so the actual output is more like

```
"support_advice": [{
        "text": "",
        "group": "check_lifestyle_26",
        "value": "Physical activity & Exercise, Overall General Health & Wellbeing"
    }]
```

**THE FULL SCRIPT**

What the script below does is loop through every element in a form and then creates JSON which then gets passed to where it needs to.

This works fine. However checkboxes are when the issue comes in. Part of the system allows you to add parts of the form again, which have the same name.

For something like a textarea, or text input, this is fine. However for checkboxes, because there may be multiple of the same name in the first instance, if I add another section that includes the checkboxes again, the script below won't be able to decipher between sections...

```
var elem = document.getElementById('rn_QuestionSubmit').elements;

            var a = [];
            var result = {};

            for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
            {
                var element = elem[i];
                var item = {};
                //item.id = element.id;
                //item.type = element.type;
                if (element.type === 'select-one') {
                    item.text = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
                }
                else {
                    item.text = '';
                }

                item.group = elem[i].dataset.group;

                if (element.type === 'radio' || element.type === 'checkbox') {
                    if (element.checked) {
                        item.value = element.value;
                        if (result[element.name]) { result[element.name].push(item) } else { result[element.name] = [item]};
                    }
                }
                else {
                    item.value = element.value;
                    if (result[element.name]) { result[element.name].push(item) } else { result[element.name] = [item]};
                }
            } 
            a.push(JSON.stringify(result));
            console.log('['+a.join(',') + ']');
            return('['+a.join(',') + ']');
```

Comment: `arr[index].value += ", " + oN.value`

Comment: ??? Not sure where to put that

Comment: Which index of `a` array should `value` property of the object be concatenated using current `element.value`?

Comment: Sorry, less understanding now...

Comment: Within the loop you can check if the given property exists in the array, if true, concatenate the value to the existing `value` property.

Comment: That's what I have been trying to do but looking at my JS snippet, I wouldn't know how to do that. Appreciate your effort in helping out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a minor change to your code to make that happen for the checkbox/radiobutton case: when the `element.name` key exists in `result` then the next check would be if the last entry in the `result` array has the same group. If so, then modify its value property, if not, do what you already did now.

Here is that part of the code:

```
        if (result[element.name]) {
            // Get the last entry in the array 
            var lastEntry = result[element.name].slice(-1)[0];
            // If same group, then concatenate the value instead of adding the item 
            if (lastEntry.group === item.group) {
                lastEntry.value += "," + element.value;
            } else {
                // You already had this:
                result[element.name].push(item);
            }
        // You already had this:
        } else { 
            result[element.name] = [item]
        }
```